# Refresh flow scope variable

Tags: grails

I am using grails web flow plugin, i create a variable

```
flow.sales = [] as List
```

Across the flow user add items to flow.sales variable, and at some point user could delete items from flow.sales

```
flow.sales.remove someItem
```

The problem is in views where I list items from flow.sales there is no change, deleted item persist, I tried this code.

```
println flow.sales //[1,2,3,4,5]
flow.sales.remove item //5
println flow.sales //[1,2,3,4]
```

In order to check that items are deleted. I tried several way to delete, by item, by index. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
flow.sales -= someItem
```

if the items are mere integers as you have shown in example.

`remove()` on List takes the index of the element that needs removal. In the above answer, `minus()` operator is used instead. Also note that a new list is created after removing the item without mutating the original list, therefore assigning it back to `flow.sales`.

Also remember, `[]` indicates an ArrayList, so there is no need to coerce it `as List`.

Comment: thanks for the answer @dmahapatro, the fact that after removing an item from a list does not change original list was the problem, flow.sales -= someItem fix the problem in a realy cool way, but now i can see another problem, after i successfuly remove the item from flow.sales i can see the list updated in the view.

Comment: Yes I guess that is what you were aiming at?